# Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
    
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-app.js";
    import {getDatabase, ref, set } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.1/firebase-database.js"
    
    
    
    const firebaseConfig = {
    
      
    };
    
    // Initialize Firebase
    
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    
    
    const db = getDatabase();
    
    function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
      const db = getDatabase();
      const reference = ref(db, 'users/' + userId);
    
      set(reference, {
        username: name,
        email: email,
        profile_picture : imageUrl
      });
    }
    
    writeUserData("ayani", "awu", "email", "url");
```

It keeps on giving me this error:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options).
> at initializeApp (api.ts:146:25)
> at getApp (api.ts:206:12)
> at no (Database.ts:321:57)
> at script.js:27:12

I'm using firebase Realtime Database and also sending it data with python

Ive tried

> ```
> import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"; 
> import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
> ```

and it still gives me

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options).
> at initializeApp (api.ts:146:25)
> at getApp (api.ts:206:12)
> at no (Database.ts:321:57)
> at script.js:27:12

I don't understand how to fix it.

this is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "type": "module",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way:

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

For the db:

```
const dataSnapShot = await admin.database().ref(apth).once('value');
```

Comment: It just says 

    script.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
        at script.js:2:18

Comment: What's in your `package.json` file? Can you post the details?

Comment: I just did in the main post